# Unclamping X and Y values from android touch events, to detect movement outside a view

Tags: android, android-layout

When a user starts a touch in a particular view and then moves the finger outside the view (while still in contact with the surface), the MotionEvent returned clamps the x/y value into coordinates inside the box.

That is, I won't get negative Y values if I move the finger above the view, for example.

Is there a way to get this raw value? getRawY seems to clamp the value as well.

I can't do anything with activities, since this is for an IME project, and the IME basically accepts a View from you and takes care of rendering etc.

Comment: did you try http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TouchDelegate.html ?

Comment: @pskink I'm not sure I understand. When I hand my "View" to the IME system, it seems to be handling everything, and I'm not sure if I can make it forward any touches to my View.

Comment: ok if you don't want to use a delegate make your ime view bigger that you normally have

Comment: @pskink but making the IME bigger mean that it'll obstruct the touches the user tries to put for the non IME parts.

Comment: seems you cannot eat cake and have cake scenario...

Comment: ok,  but what about returning false if action is ACTION_DOWN and you touch the extended part of your keyboard view and return true if you touch the normal part?

Comment: @pskink nope, that just blocks the whole touch for the view below the keyboard, which isn't really acceptable :/

Comment: Do you create the view?  In other words, is it possible for you to override methods inherited from android.view.View?

Comment: @Turix yes, I created the view, but the View is created in a nethod "onCreateInputView" which is returned to the OS. The method is from the InputMethodService subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH on the window associated with your view.  That should make it work.

I do have another way to do it, but you really don't want to use it (it involves the ugly hack of making a partially transparent full screen keyboard) so lets try this first.

Here's the horrible hack you don't want to use this method:

1)Add a transparent view above your keyboard, taking up the rest of the screen.

2)In onComputeInsets, define your touchable insets to be a REGION, and pass it a region made up of only your keyboard

3)In onTouchEvent, on a ACTION_DOWN set a flag that says we're in touch mode, and make sure to invalidate your view (this will cause onComputeInsets to be called again)

4)In onComputeInsets, look at the value of that touch mode flag.  If false, use the insets set in 2.  If true, set the entire screen as touchable

5)In onTouchEvent, on a ACTION_UP or ACTION_CANCEL clear that flag and call invalidate to reset the insets

What that will do is tell the framework that touches on that transparent view do no belong to the keyboard (so they'll be sent to the app) unless you're in touch mode in which case we tell the framework we want all touches anywhere.  Its hacky, but I've done this kind of code before and it does work.  It just requires you to play with onComputeInsets, which is almost undocumented (they added minimal documentation a few versions ago) and has been used by probably about 20 people in the world.  Its an ugly api.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I have access to the window as I'm making an IME, and the IME system basically just takes a View which I created. Literally returned from a function I had to overwrite - doesn't seem like it lets me modify anything else outside the view.

Comment: You can get the window token from the view.  That's also how an IME displays a dialog

Comment: Edited with the hacky solution.  The hacky solution works, its just a nightmare to code